# Apple Wallet Event Pass

Tags: ios, swift, laravel, wallet

I am developing an iOS application using swift as a front-end and PHP as a back-end (using Laravel framework). One of the features in my app is booking tickets for events.

I would like to integrate with Apple’s wallet to add the ticket (pass) to the  Wallet.

My question is: is there any detailed resources (e.g, source code of previous projects) or any helpful notes ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Take a look at this helpful library https://github.com/aydenp/PassEncoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that first you should check PassKit documentation from Apple to understand correctly how it works(https://developer.apple.com/wallet/). Then maybe this webside could works for you: https://github.com/tschoffelen/php-pkpass

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to work through Apple's [Wallet Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH1-SW1) first. Wallet used to be named "Passbook" and the cards "Passes"; searching for these terms may get you tutorials - older ones, obviously - that may still help you get it done.